# Is Thread.sleep better than continually checking to see if a condition is met?

Tags: java, multithreading, platform-sdk

I want this program to run indefinitely and I am not sure of the best way to maximize cpu and memory efficiency. I have created a thread that handles responses from a server, these responses will come back every 20 seconds or so. However, I have to make sure that the server is still sending responses, otherwise I must get responses from a new server. Every time a response comes back, the current system time is stored in 'lastRTime'. Is there a better alternative to Thread.sleep() here? This is at the end of my main thread.

```
while(true) {
    Thread.sleep(checkInterval);
        if (System.currentTimeMillis()-lastRTime > timeDiffThreshold) {
            pmsi.beginClose();    //Close the current connection
            makeConnection(backupHost,backupPort);
        }
    }
}
```

Would it be better to simply not sleep?

Comment: And the `lastRTime` is updated in a place where response is received ?

Comment: It's better to use something like a `ScheduledExecutor` to execute the action on a regular schedule. But yes, sleeping means you won't max out your CPU doing very little useful work.

Comment: There's no need for the *loop.* You have the computation to tell you exactly *how* long to sleep *for,* unless you have to worry about clock resets and DST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best alternative (but not the must-be) is to use `ScheduledExecutor` and submit your checking to run after `checkInterval`. In case if you would get response earlier, you can cancel that task and resubmit with new delay.

So i would be like that (pseudocode):

1. schedule response check to run after `checkInterval`
2. Handle response
3. If "check" task is still pending, cancel it, update `lastRTime`, and reschedule (point 1)

If check task would fire, then reschedule again.

This way you ommit waiting period between lastRTime and Thread.sleep() invokation timestamp